# Matlab verification of file after copy

Tags: matlab, file-transfer

I would like to know whether we have a way using matlab to check the integrity of a file after copying to another folder.

I have 8 files in folder `A`. I will copy them in detination folder `B`. But at the end I want to verify that the copied files in folder `B` are exactly the same (size, integrity, data in the file) of the original file in folder `A`.

Comment: You can open each file up and check... this depends entirely what is in the files, and perhaps why you'd have any doubts that they were copied correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You could run a `system` command to compute a checksum & then parse it out from the captured output.  It would depend on your OS which command would be appropriate.

The code below should get you started.  I included examples for Windows and a little bit for Linux.  However since I don't have my Linux Box turned on I didn't include any code to parse the cksum values from the `system` output.

```
if ispc
    srcCmd = sprintf('CertUtil -hashfile %s MD5',fullPathToSourceFile);
    dstCmd = sprintf('CertUtil -hashfile %s MD5',fullPathToDestFile);

    [stat_S,cmdout_S] = system(srcCmd);
    [stat_D,cmdout_D] = system(dstCmd);

    parsed_S = textscan(cmdout_S,'%s','delimiter','\n');
    MD5_S    = parsed_S{1}{2};
    parsed_D = textscan(cmdout_D,'%s','delimiter','\n');
    MD5_D    = parsed_D{1}{2};

    if strcmp(MD5_S,MD5_D)
        disp('MD5 Good   :)')
    else
        disp('MD5 Bad    :(')
    end

elseif isunix 
    srcCmd = sprintf('cksum %s',fullPathToSourceFile);
    dstCmd = sprintf('cksum %s',fullPathToDestFile);

    [stat_S,cmdout_S] = system(srcCmd);
    [stat_D,cmdout_D] = system(dstCmd);  
    %Insert parsing & checking code for Linux
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to check your files, it's kind of 'manually', we just open two files and check the data. `MD5` check must be faster, but in my viewpoint, it would be changed accidentally when we view&save the file without changing.

```
clc; clear;
fA=dir('E:/folderA');
fB=dir('E:/folderB');
for i=1:length(fA)

  pos=find(cellfun(@(x)isequal(x,fA(i).name),{fB.name}));
  if (fA(i).isdir == 1 || isempty(pos)) 
      continue; 
  end

  %open file in FolderA
  fid=fopen(['E:/folderA/' fA(i).name],'r'); 
  dataA=fread(fid,inf,'char');
  fclose(fid);

  %open file in FolderB
  fid=fopen(['E:/folderB/' fA(i).name],'r'); 
  dataB=fread(fid,inf,'char');
  fclose(fid);

  %Isequal
  if (isequal(dataA,dataB))
    disp(['file ' fA(i).name ' is exactly the same.'])
  else
    %print something
  end

end
```